# MutableState doesn't recompose UI

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have this BaseViewModel that handle track of my Exoplayer

```
@HiltViewModel
open class BaseViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val context: Context,
    private val myPlayer: MyPlayer
) : ViewModel(), PlayerEvents {

 private val _selectedTrack = mutableStateOf<Track?>(null)
    var selectedTrack =_selectedTrack


  private fun onTrackSelected(index: Int) {
        if (selectedTrackIndex == -1) isTrackPlay = true
        if (selectedTrackIndex == -1 || selectedTrackIndex != index) {
            _tracks.resetTracks()
            selectedTrackIndex = index
            _selectedTrack.value = tracks[selectedTrackIndex]
            setUpTrack()
        }
    }

override fun onPlayPauseClick() {
        myPlayer.playPause()
        _selectedTrack.value = _selectedTrack.value?.apply { state = myPlayer.playerState.value }
    }

}
```

the mutableState recomposing in `onTrackSelected` method, but it didn't work when I call `onPlayPause`. I tried to log the value of `_selectedTrack.value` at the and operation and it showed that the value has update
I also trying change mutableState to mutableStateFlow but nothing change.

I want selectedTrack in my baseViewModel to recompose my UI so it will update my play/pause toggle

```
Image(
                   modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                            onPlayPause()
                        },
                        painter = painterResource(
                            id = if (selectedTrack.state == PlayerStates.STATE_PLAYING) R.drawable.ic_pause
                            else R.drawable.ic_play
                        ),
                        contentDescription = "pause",
                        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(
                            MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
                            BlendMode.SrcIn
                        )
                    )
```

Comment: Does `MyPlayer.playPause()` set the state before it returns, or does that happen asynchronously? If async, the set following it might run before the state has changed and still see the old value

Comment: `var selectedTrack =_selectedTrack` Looks like two different bugs waiting to happen. Should be `val selectedTrack: State<Track?> get() = _selectedTrack`

Comment: Easiest/safest way is `var selectedTrack by mutableStateOf<Track?>(null) private set`. (with better formatting than I can do in a comment...). This hides the `State` use from the caller (but still works with Compose snapshots) and doesn't allow the caller to set it directly. You also no longer need the `_selectedTrack` property.  (Personally I'm not a fan of using Compose state inside a view model, but it is a little less code than using Flows in the VM and then having to collect them in the UI)

Comment: @Tenfour04 It's work for one case. I don't know why it doesn't happen in another case. Actually I use `selectedTrack` for 2 component, which one component is inside many compose component, so I pass the `selectedTrack` for every component and it doesn't work there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compose is using an internal caching mechanism that compares values. When doing MutableState.value = value, what Compose does is actually comparing the previous value and the new value of the MutableState. Since you used the “apply” operator you’re setting the same object as the new value. Which means Compose will detect the previous and new state are equals, so a new composition is not triggered.

To solve that you have two choices -

1 You can make Compose to not check for equal values by doing -

```
private val _selectedTrack = mutableStateOf<Track?>(null, policy = neverEqualPolicy())
```

2 make your Track class a data class, and then use instead of .apply() the .copy() method to change the state fields.

Out of the two options above, I would recommend option number 2, which seems to be more suitable for your specific case. Option number 1 should be avoided and used only in specific cases. An example of a valid use of option number 1 is when your state is a Collection.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use option number 2 because my Track isn't data class due to used extends for another class

Comment: @annng then better implement your own deep copy function

Answer (score 0):

When updating a state, use `copy` function for compose to detect.

```kotlin
override fun onPlayPauseClick() {
    myPlayer.playPause()
    _selectedTrack.value = _selectedTrack.value?.copy(state = myPlayer.playerState.value)
}
```